# XSLT code for XFF Http Header Extraction in IBM DataPower

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

I need an XSLT code to extract the X-Forwarded-for HTTP header from the incoming traffic on the DataPower load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:variable name="xFwdFor" select="dp:http-request-header('X-Forwarded-for')"/>
```

This will give you the request header named 'X-Forwarded-for' in a variable called "xFwdFor".